# Email data from a Magento 2 Custom Contact form

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2.

I have added an HTML contact form in a CMS page, but I am not able to make the submit button work the way I want it to. If I set it up as

```
<form action="mailto:email@yourdomain.com" method="post">
```

then hitting the submit button opens a new window. I've also tried a Javascript solution, but that's not working either.

I have also copied `form.html` and used the code in the CMS page to call the form, but clicking on the submit button then redirects me to the 'contact us'  page and gives me a 'we can not process your request right now' error.

What I want to do is just to send the data to a prespecified email address when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: codes? errors? problems?

Comment: <form>
<div class="container">
Name<input name="name" required="" type="text" /> 
Email<input name="email" required="" type="text" /> 
Phone<input maxlength="10" name="number" required="" type="text" /> Product<input name="productname" required="" type="text" /> Quantity (GM or KG)<input name="quantity" required="" type="text" /> <input checked="checked" name="product" type="radio" value="organic" /> Organic<br /> <input name="product" type="radio" value="inorganic" /> Inorganic<br /> <input name="product" type="radio" value="both" /> Both<br />

Comment: This is my code.. now I want to get an email with all the details field in form.

Comment: If I am adding mailto:email then it opens a new window but doesn not send email